# Separately documenting the elements in a destructuring assignment

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation

In Swift, you can write a documentation comment for a single declaration like this:

```swift
/// The title of the view.
private var title: String
```

This documentation is automatically displayed by Xcode when you put your cursor on a use of `title`. You can use Markdown along with some Swift-specific semantic formatting, as described in [this NSHipster article](https://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/).

Is it possible to separately document the variables resulting from a destructuring assignment like this?

```swift
private var (titlePromise, titleSeal) = Promise<String>.pending()
```

I tried what I thought was the obvious thing,

```swift
private var (
    /// Promise that will resolve when we receive the view's title.
    titlePromise,
    /// Resolver function for the view's title.
    titleSeal
) = Promise<String>.pending()
```

but Xcode did not pick up on these comments. I found that it was possible to put a doc comment before both,

```swift
/// Promise and resolver for the view's title.
private var (titlePromise, titleSeal) = Promise<String>.pending()
```

in which case Xcode applies that documentation to both `promise` and `seal`. This is not ideal, since those variables—while related—are separate types with separate uses.

Is it possible to separately document both (or all) of the elements in a tuple assignment in a way that Xcode will pick up on?

Answer (score 0):

Even I had same requirement earlier but I didn't found any such solution. Though apple providing the rich documentation with the help of writing different types of code commenting, till now there is no way of writing documentation comment for a tuple property. But, alternatively I come across writing like this.

````
/// A tupple property whcih holds the values of title
/// - Parameters:
///     - titlePromise: So on so.....
///     - titleSeal: So on so.....
/// ```
/// mTitle = Promise<String>.pending()
/// print(mTitle.titlePromise)
/// ```
var mTitle: (titlePromise: String, titleSeal: String)?
````